# How to access objective c class extension in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, class-extensions

I had many **Class Extensions** written before, like :

My header file, NSDate+convenience.h:

```
@interface NSDate (Convenience)
+ (NSDate *)dateFromMyString:(NSString *)dateString 
           withDateFormatStr:(NSString *)dateFormatStr;
@end
```

My Obj-C implementation file, NSDate+convenience.m:

```
@implementation NSDate (Convenience)
+ (NSDate *)dateFromMyString:(NSString *)dateString
              withDateFormatStr:(NSString *)dateFormatStr {

   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
   [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
   [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormatStr];

   return [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
@end
```

I use my NSDate Class Extension in objective c by :

```
[NSDate dateFromMyString:[NSDate date] withDateFormatStr:@"yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS"]
```

But when want to use it in Swift something like :

```
NSDate.dateFromMyString(dateString: dateStr, DateFormatStr: "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS")
```

or

```
NSDate.dateFromMyString(bla bla bla ...)
```

Anyway, the NSDate has no member like 'dateFromMyString', I have many many class extension which I wrote before. Do I need to implement these Class Extension in Swift again.

**I have to underline that**, I can use my custom normal Obj-C classes properties and methods in Swift, but I can't use a obj-C file that is an extension of the Obj-C. **So please do not give me a link 'How to call Objective-C code from Swift'** . Please **understand** my question.

Comment: is this a typo? Shouldn't it be `NSDate.dateFromMyString(dateString: dateStr, withDateFormatStr: "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS")`

Comment: I say something like that, anyway, it cannot find any member like 'dateFromMyString bla bla bla ...'

Comment: Have you any bridge header file on your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: I have a bridge header file that I can use all my other custom Obj-C classes properties and methods in Swift. I only cannot access extension of the Obj-C.

Comment: @Nijat2018 I think the point is `NSDate+convenience.h` in the bridging header?

Comment: You should call it in Swift like this: `let date = NSDate(fromMyString: "String",
                          withDateFormatStr: "yyyy.MM.dd")`. And, of course, the extension header must be imported in the bridging header

Comment: Not working, my Class Extension is inside a framework, and I put the framework header inside  bridging header